# How to add a HUD? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, ios

I am trying to have some controls appear when you push a button and have it disappear when you press a different button. Right now the HUD is comprised of an image view, and some custom buttons in a UIView called "credits". I've managed to have it disappear using:

```
[credits removeFromSuperview];
```

How do I have it reappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a UIImageView, you should...

```
[self.view addSubview:credits];
```

... assuming you've not released it already.  On a side note, there is a really good HUD for iOS here: http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just set the view to be hidden

```
[self.view setHidden:YES];
```

While it's hidden, you can also update the view and then show again

```
[self.view setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better set their `hidden` property to whether `YES` or `NO`

Answer (score 0):

This method will toggle the UIView credits hidden property

```
- (void) toggleCredits {

[credits setHidden:![credits isHidden]];

}
```